# How to change the distribution of classes?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, distributions, classification, mathematical-statistics

I have two classes [0,1] and I want to evaluate algorithm on different distributions of classes. I did label flipping incrementally such as 0%, 10%,20%,....,90%,100%.  Does label flipping change the distributions of classes or just add noise to the dataset. I attached figure for label flipping with different percentages 10%,30%,50%,70%,90%,100% .[image]

The purpose of doing this is to evaluate algorithm on different distributions of dataset. I have a weak knowledge in machine learning and distribution. Thank you for any help you can offer.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: It does change the distribution of classes, but not necessarily in a reasonable way for what you want to do (which isn't quite clear to me). If you want to evaluate a supervised or unsupervised classification algorithm, for example, using your original classes is reasonable because true classes could look like that. However, imagining in such a situation with two proper "data analytic" classes (your original classes) that there are two other true classes that randomly distribute over the original ones is something of a stretch. It's probably better to move the class means closer to each other.

Comment: @Lewian I want to evaluate two methods , which method is Bayes consistent that can achieve best performance on different distributions of dataset. This is way I do label flipping.